# Android ImageButton not enforcing transparency in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, transparency, android-relativelayout, android-imagebutton

I am trying to place two image buttons and some text on a single line. Here is the XML for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mycompany xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sectionDelete"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/button_delete" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sectionDelete"
            android:text="test"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/navigation_bar"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sectionAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button_add" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</LinearLayout>
</mycompany>
```

The selector XML for each of the buttons in drawable:

`button_delete.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/delete_button_pressed"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/delete_button"
      android:state_focused="true" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/delete_button" />
</selector>
```

`button_add.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_add_pressed"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_add_normal"
      android:state_focused="true" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_add_normal" />
</selector>
```

In the builder all looks well:

[image]

But in the application the gray background is lost and the edges of the image (which are transparent) are shown, but only for the first image:

[image]

Strangely, the first image button is not recognizing the transparent background of the image. Additionally I needed to mess with the width and height of the RelativeLayout and the first ImageButton to even get it close to the right size. With the 2nd I did not have to do anything. There is nothing special with the first image.

Here are the images from the directory:

[image]

One last issue - How do you make the text wrap before the 2nd image if it is too long for the space? Right now it writes under the 2nd image before wrapping:

[image]

Here are all the delete images. Seem to have transparent backgrounds, but I am far from a Gimp expert. Also not sure if StackOverflow keeps the original..

[image]
[image]

### Update

I have verified the images are transparent. The image still has the white background. I have also updated the XML to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mycompany xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sectionDelete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button_delete" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sectionDelete"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sectionDelete"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sectionAdd"
            android:text="test"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/navigation_bar"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sectionAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button_add" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</LinearLayout>
</mycompany>
```

Comment: Use android:background="@null" on ImageButton

Comment: Does your images has white background when you open them in an Image Viewer?

Comment: In Gimp and Paint 3d it shows them transparent. Having a coworker verify with PhotoShop.

Comment: Co-worker verified. He also cleared the transparency and added it back in. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
    <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/sectionDelete"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:src="@drawable/button_delete"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure that image background is transparent?

Comment: It looks transparent in Gimp, but I am beginning to wonder if the something else is going on...going to to try and test in another tool

Answer (score 0):

Use "@null" like background on ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/bkash"
    android:id="@+id/bid1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@null" />
```

Comment: Didn't work. Wondering if there is something I am missing. Perhaps the image(s) have some issue? Though the 2nd one seems to be fine.

Comment: Try this: the 2nd image use 'button_add.xml' on android:background - change the first one to android:background instead of android:src

Comment: Good catch - changed it, and that allows me to get rid of height/width settings, but still has white background. Looks transparent in Gimp, but going to look closer at both those images.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the actual PNG file you are using as an icon for your delete button (screenshot from Windows's Explorer showing this file on your disk isn't quite enough), but I am almost sure that this file lacks an alpha channel. Instead, there is a white color on every pixel you'd like to be set with zero alpha channel value.

Opening your graphic in some image editor and changing these white pixels to transparent will solve your problem, but as for the reason why your layout "looks different" in builder than on your device, it's because there is a default theme applied by the system to every app, you can read more about it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html

This default, OS and device specific set of values determines things that aren't determined by app's authors.

In the case of your device, its OS determined app's background color to be gray, which wasn't the case with your builder. Your builder chose the background to be white. Your delete button's graphic never was transparent, but on the white background of your builder it looked like it was.

To make it look like on builder, you need to specifically apply the background by yourself to the root of your view. In this case, it's a LinearLayout which should look like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff">
```

Answer (score 0):

1)  @DimDim had the right solution, if it didn't work, the delete button may have white background in the image, cross check with a png viewer.

2) To prevent overflow of text, try this

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sectionDelete"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sectionAdd"
            android:text="test"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/navigation_bar"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

And put the sectionAdd Image button above this textview in the XML as this textview needs reference to the sectionAdd.

Comment: Perfect on the wrapping! The images look transparent in Gimp, but I will see if I can pull them into something else that should allow transparency.

Comment: @StephenMcCormick glad to help :)

Comment: Doh - one other issue with this. On the first instance the Delete button is gone. This forces the text to right. Any way to pull that left?

Comment: Did it programmatically. :(